# How can I use the keyboard to choose how to paste text in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007, copy-paste

While using a word processor I prefer to user the keyboard almost exclusively, but when pasting text in MS Word I seem forced to use the mouse. I can find no way to specify how to treat formatting (keep source / match destination / text only) on a one-off basis without using the mouse (distracting and slow) or altering my default settings (even worse).

Is there a way to do this? It seems to me I need **either** a keyboard shortcut to enter the *Paste Options* dialogue after pasting **or** a different command that I can use to specify the formatting option. I looked at *Paste Special*, but that only seems to provide one relevant option, namely ‘text only’ (*Unformatted Text*), while I want ‘keep’ or ‘match’ as well.

I am using MS Word 2007, but an answer applying to other versions would obviously be more generally useful.

<sub>P.S. I use MS Office’s Dutch UI for compatibility with colleagues, so various keys and texts above may be inaccurate.</sub>

Comment: In Word 2013 when you paste the auto-format box shows up.  You can then hit CTRL (then let go) to bring up the sub-menu of paste types, then hit K, M or T to choose how you want to paste it.  Does that not work in 2007?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: No! All I can do is het Escape to get rid of the icon — makes me wonder if I can use 2013 in our organisation! Nice to know, anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would an Outlook 2007 macro to automate Paste Special - Unformatted Text look like?](http://superuser.com/questions/25170/what-would-an-outlook-2007-macro-to-automate-paste-special-unformatted-text-lo)

Comment: I realize the marked dupe is for *Outlook* 2007, but Outlook uses Word as it's editor, so the macro should work the same when used in Word.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Also, I want to be able to choose Keep or Match as well. Still, perhaps it is a start.

Comment: Make multiple macros, only use [wdFormatOriginalFormatting and/or wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237976(v=office.12).aspx) insatead of wdFormatPlainText. :)

Comment: Since the suggest duplicate does not cover the ground I want to remove it, but I don’t know how.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Thanks, I may try that and report back. (Also interested to see that ‘match’ means ‘surrounding formatting with emphasis’!)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: As per comment on answer from Lernkurve, I made macros  and assigned them to `<Ctrl>`+`<Alt>`+`<Shift>` + `<`, `|`, `>` respectively for keep,text,merge. This works fine and is good enough for me.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: P.S. I’d be delighted to upgrade, but this is a company system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the useful answer by Lernkurve, I conclude that ‘*Paste Special…*’ does **not** do the job, while mapping keystrokes to macros created from the ‘paste mode’ dialogue does. Since his first two options apply Word 2013 and up, anyone stuck on 2007 will have to create and map macros.

#### Recording Macros

To record macros, you need the <kbd>Developers</kbd> tab enabled in the ribbon, in <kbd>Word Options</kbd>/<kbd>Popular Options</kbd>.

#### Macros for the Paste Modes

The macros needed to do the job, recorded by entering the choice menu after pasting are:

```
Sub PasteOriginal()
' Paste with option ‘original formatting’
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
End Sub
Sub PasteMatching()
' Paste with option ‘match destination’
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis)
End Sub
Sub PasteText()
' Paste with option ‘only text’
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
End Sub
```

I mapped these to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+(<kbd><</kbd>|<kbd>|</kbd>|<kbd>></kbd>) for <kbd>keep format</kbd>, <kbd>text only</kbd> and <kbd>merge format</kbd> respectively. I chose the modifier keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to avoid clashes with predefined mappings,  while (<kbd><</kbd>|<kbd>|</kbd>|<kbd>></kbd>) suggested to me looking back (to the source format), neutral and looking forward (to the destination format), even if those are not really what happens.

#### Meaning of the Options

The meaning of the options is described as follows on MSDN (I have not tested this thoroughly):

- <kbd>Keep source formatting</kbd> (`wdFormatOriginalFormatting`): “Preserves original formatting of the pasted material” – *I presume this includes styles, but wonder what happens if style names clash. I presume that all current formatting is ignored.*
- <kbd>Merge formatting</kbd> (`wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis`): “Matches the formatting of the pasted text to the formatting of surrounding text” – *I **believe** this means that the characters from the source and any emphasis* (**bold**, *italic*, _ underlining _) *are inserted in the current formatting, while all other original formatting is ignored.*
- <kbd>Keep Text only</kbd> (`wdFormatPlainText`): “Pastes as plain, unformatted text.” – Only the characters from the source are inserted, in the current formatting.

#### Options in Paste Special

I investigated the options in *Paste Special…*, recording macros for each option, as in the screenshot of the dialogue in Lernkurve’s answer. Some of them seemed to behave as <kbd>keep format</kbd> (sometimes doing odd extra things), others as <kbd>text only</kbd>, but *none* as <kbd>merge format</kbd>. (To get all options I had to paste text with some extra formatting, otherwise I just got two options; my set of options included “Picture (Windows Metafile)”, not in his screenshot.)

These were the results:

```
Sub SpecialPasteDoc() ' MS Office Word-document object
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement _
        :=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
Sub SpecialPasteRTF() ' Formatted text (RTF)

    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
End Sub
Sub SpecialPastePlain() ' Unformatted text
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
End Sub
Sub SpecialPastePic() ' Picture (Windows Metafile)
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
End Sub
Sub SpecialPastePicEnhanced() ' Picture (Enhanced Metafile)
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
End Sub
Sub SpecialPasteHTML() 'HTML Format
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteHTML, Placement:= _
        wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
Sub SpecialPasteUnicodeText() ' Unformatted Unicode Text
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=20, Placement:=wdInLine, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Solution 1: with <kbd>context menu</kbd> key

With Word 2013, you can click

1. the <kbd>context menu</kbd> key
2. followed by either

   - <kbd>K</kbd> for *Keep Source Formatting*,
   - <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> for *Merge Formatting* (yes, strangely enough, an additional <kbd>Enter</kbd> was required) or
   - <kbd>T</kbd> for *Keep Text Only*.

[image: Special Paste with context menu key]

The <kbd>context menu</kbd> key is this one:

[image: context menu key]

<sub>Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key</sub>

#### Solution 2: with ribbon menu accelerator keys

In Word 2013, click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, then either <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image: Special paste via ribbon]

#### Solution 3: with *Special Paste* dialog

You can

1. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (instead of just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to open the *Paste Special* dialog,
2. then use <kbd>Arrow down</kbd> or <kbd>Arrow up</kbd> to change the default selection
3. and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

#### Solution 4: with assigning a keyboard shortcut to a macro

1. Create a separate macro for each *Special Paste* option as shown in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/407119/32245)
2. Assign a keyboard shortcut to it via menu `File` → `Options` → `Customize Ribbon` → `Customize` → `Customize Keyboard`

Comment: As I said in the question, this only offers _Unformatted Text_ (which I called “Text only”, not having the English version. None of the other options sounds as if they provide “keep source” or “match destination” formatting (and the help text was unhelpful).

Comment: @PJTraill _Unformatted Text_ does "match destination" and _Formatted Text (RTF)_ does "keep source". I've updated the screenshot to make it clearer. The default for the regular `Ctrl`+`V` could be changed to "text only" -- but you wrote you didn't want to alter the default.

Comment: I’ll try that out — but the dialogue you can click on after inserting offers three possibilities, matching the constants documented at [the link provided by ‘TECHIE007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237976%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in their comment on my question. How can one obtain all three? If one can, how could MS be so obfuscatory in their UI? (Rhetorical question!)

Comment: @PJTraill You mentioning the "three possibilities" made me think of another solution which I have added as _Solution 1_ above.

Comment: @PJTraill I've added another way documented as _Solution 2_ above. How about that one?

Comment: @PJTraill I've added yet another idea as _Solution 4_.

Comment: Thank-you for the effort, you cover a lot of ground! Perhaps you could mark (2) as only applying to MS Word 2013(?) and up, like (1). In (1) you might also mention, _pace_ ‘TECHIE007, that `<Ctrl>` also brings up the menu. Unfortunately I am stuck (as the question says) on 2007, so (1) and (2), while useful to others, do not help me. In (3) it is still unclear how the menu choices relate to the K/M/T of the first two solutions. ‘TECHIE007 had also suggested the same as (4), which is what I have done, assigning them to `<Ctrl>`+`<Alt>`+`<Shift>` + `<`, `|`, `>` respectively for keep,text,merge.

Comment: I’m afraid I have accepted my own answer instead of yours, as it applies to Work 2007, gives the details I needed, and your suggestion of _Paste Special_ does not seem to work. But your answer is definitely useful, especially for other versions, and still has my upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for 2013 and later, but I can provide the answer for 2010 and earlier: `Alt + H, V, S, V`

That key combination is easy to hit quickly. Note, this will bring up the paste special dialog, but you can continue, hitting a shortcut key (first letter) to select "unformatted unicode text" (or whatever it's called), `enter` to close the dialog, etc.

For match, [Microsoft says](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/paste-special-match-destination-shortcut/574cbba0-2848-493d-9a42-fcc59867a605): `Ctrl + V, Ctrl, M`